# Compiling a code in TeXnicCenter produces an empty PDF without any warning and error

Tags: pdf, texniccenter, build-system

When I compile a code in TeXnicCenter, it builds a pdf without my modifications, giving: 0 errors 0 warnings 0 pages.

I'm not an expert but I've tried everything to make it work without reach any solution. It should be a settings problem, because with same files but using my friend's pc the code works.

Comment: Could you post the code for us to see, too?

Comment: Have you checked the log file outside of Texniccenter? I remember that I had something similar before, but in my case the pdf was created despite the editor showing 0 pages produced. This however was with an old version of Texniccenter.

Comment: If it reads 0 pages, but you still have a PDF, you're looking at the old PDF. See if the simplest possible document builds first. If it does, start cutting down your document until you have the smallest possible document that fails to build. If the simplest possible document fails, then you may want to reinstall TxC entirely.